# fluent migrator is not creating synonym

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, database-migration, fluent-migrator

I am using [Fluent Migrator 1.2.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentMigrator/%22Fluent%20Migrator%22)

and i am getting exception while i am trying to create synonym

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

StackTrace :

```
   at FluentMigrator.Builders.Execute.ExecuteExpressionRoot.Sql(String sqlStatement)
   at Tavisca.Catapult.Database.Rates.Migrations._004TagsAtProductLevel.Up() in d:\Projects\IMS\Git Source\tavisca-catapult-databases\Tavisca.Catapult.Database.Migrations\Tavisca.Catapult.Database.Rates\Migrations\004TagsAtProductLevel.cs:line 27
   at Tavisca.Catapult.Database.Migrator.Program.Main(String[] args) in d:\Projects\IMS\Git Source\tavisca-catapult-databases\Tavisca.Catapult.Database.Migrations\Tavisca.Catapult.Database.Migrator\Program.cs:line 17
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

migration code is as follows

```
        var contentDbConnectionString =
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBContent"].ConnectionString;

        var ratesDbConnectionString =
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBRate"].ConnectionString;

        var contentDbConnectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(contentDbConnectionString);

        var sqlConnectionBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ratesDbConnectionString);

        var command = "CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[Table1] FOR [" + sqlConnectionBuilder.DataSource + "].[" + contentDbConnectionStringBuilder.InitialCatalog + "].[dbo].[Table1];" +
               "CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[Table2] FOR [" + sqlConnectionBuilder.DataSource + "].["+ contentDbConnectionStringBuilder.InitialCatalog + "].[dbo].[Table2];";
        Execute.Sql(command); // Exception will come here.
```

same script runs perfectly fine in query analyzer and synonym works too.

Comment: Maybe it has no support for it?

Comment: Does this really work in query analyzer? I get the following error when trying to run similar code to yours. The error was There is already an object named 'dbo.Table1' in the database.
There is already an object named 'dbo.Table2' in the database. If I change the name of the synonyms then it works fine.

Comment: @DanielLee the script is working fine in query analyzer, change the synonym name if you are creating synonym in a database that have tables, in my case tables are in other database and synonyms are created in another.

Comment: @d.Siva two questions: 1. Can you show an example of the sql (is it similar to the example I posted in your Github issue) 2. How are you running FluentMigrator? Your stacktrace looks strange. Do other migrations work?